# How to get current viewed page's locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I've integrated RefineryCMS with my rails-devise app, In the `ApplicationController`, I used to set local like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_tld || I18n.default_locale
end

def extract_locale_from_tld
    parsed_locale = params[:locale] || ((lang = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && lang[/^[a-z]{2}/])
    parsed_locale= 'en' if parsed_locale.nil?
    I18n.available_locales.include?(parsed_locale.to_sym) ? parsed_locale  : nil
  end
```

Thus, this will make locale variable handy in the application.html.haml, which I will be using to pick a locale-based css

But, when I view a RefineryCSS localized page, `extract_locale_from_tld` above will fail to get the viewed page locale, it will return always en, how can I do the following:

1. Check if the current view is RefineryCSS page related?
2. Get the locale of the viewed RefineryCSS page? (The locale chosen using gem `refinerycms-i18n`)

Any help is indeed appreciated!